# Cordova plugin network information doesn't work on desktop Windows 10 app

Tags: android, cordova, windows-10, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I am making hybrid application in IntelXDK for Android and desktop version Windows 10 (appx) and I use the cordova-plugin-network-information to check internet connection. When I test my app on Android device it works fine, but in Windows 10 desktop app nothing happens, what could be the problem?

Here's my checkConnection.js

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

function onOffline() {
   alert('Not connected.');
   document.getElementById("networkInfo").textContent = "No connection";
}

function onOnline() {
   document.getElementById("networkInfo").textContent = "Connected";   
}
```

Comment: i am facing same issue. found any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've tried a lot of ways to do it but without any effect.